# Optimal pure state decomposition of bipartite mixed states

Tags: entanglement

Suppose I have a 2-qubit mixed state given by $\rho$ whose concurrence is $C$. I am interested in finding the optimal pure state decomposition of $\rho=\sum_{i=1}^4 p_i|ψ_i⟩⟨ψ_i|$ such that $C(\psi_i)=C$. Is there any way to get this decomposition or at least any relationship between $|ψ_1⟩,|ψ_2⟩$ and so on?

I tried taking $C=2\sqrt{\lambda_0\lambda_1}$ where $|ψ_i⟩=\sqrt{λ_0}|0_i⟩|0_i⟩+\sqrt{λ_1}|1_i⟩|1_i⟩$, where $|0_i⟩=\alpha_i|0⟩+β_i|1⟩$ and $|1_i⟩=β_i^\ast|0⟩−\alpha_i^\ast|1⟩$ with $|\alpha_i|^2+|β_i|^2=1$. However, I couldn't proceed from here.

---

[***Cross-posted on physics.SE***](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/798845/58382)

Comment: Do you mean that all four states $|\psi_i\rangle$ must have the same concurrence? Are you certain such a pure-state decomposition exists for all mixed states?

Comment: Yes, at least for the two qubit states as you define the '$E(\rho)=min\sum p_iE(\psi_i)$' and since '$E=C$' here is convex, all states must have same concurrence, as mentioned in Wooters's paper.

Comment: Please crosslink crossposts.

Comment: Basically, this is discussed over one-and-a-half or so pages in the Wootters paper. Can you be more specific what you struggle with?